# Cannot parse Json to data class using kotlinx.serialization

Tags: android, generics, serialization, kotlin, retrofit

In an Android project, I am trying to parse a Json response from a remote endpoint using **kotlinx.serialization** and **Retrofit**. I am using Jake Warthon's https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter to set the converter when setting up the retrofit instance

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(stringBased(contentType, ::parse, ::stringify))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

I have the following model annotated with @Serializable, which I want to use to parse the Json response

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Response<out T>(val groups: List<GroupsResponse<T>>)
```

Note that both the Response and the nested GroupsResponse define a generic type. I've been looking through the [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/master/docs) but I haven't been able to understand how generics and **kotlinx.serialization** play together, although it does mention it supports generics and that you should access the serializer for those models using the generated **serializer** methods. I've set up the project to use the right plugins as per the docs on **kotlinx.serialization** and Jake's library, but the problem is that the project is not even compiling as I am getting the following kind of errors when the build process executes the **kaptDebugKotlin** gradle task

```
e: /Users/nico/Dev/git/edreams/workshops/K-Places/data/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/edreams/android/workshops/kotlin/data/venues/remote/response/Response.java:75: error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
public static final class $serializer implements kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer<com.edreams.android.workshops.kotlin.data.venues.remote.response.Response<? extends T>> {

e: /Users/nico/Dev/git/edreams/workshops/K-Places/data/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/edreams/android/workshops/kotlin/data/venues/remote/response/GroupsResponse.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer<T0> typeSerial0) {
symbol:   class T0
location: class $serializer
```

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try using Any instead of T.